# SVG fill url(#linearGradient) is not applied

Tags: google-chrome, animation, svg, gradient

The snippet below shows exactly the problem I'm facing. The Gradient defined in the `<defs>` tag above is not effective in Chrome, but only in Firefox.

This issue was reported to me from my client in the last month, and I couldn't find any related problems, so that's why I opened a new question.

Thanks, Damianos

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 873.45 248.1" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#0a94df" stop-opacity=".6">
                <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#0a94df;#cdcbf7;#cdcbf7;#0a94df;" dur="15s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animate attributeName="offset" values="0;.20;.40;.60;.40;.20;0;" dur="15s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </stop>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0a94df" stop-opacity=".95">
                <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#fff;#cdcbf7;#0a94df;#cdcbf7;#fff;#0a94df;#cdcbf7;#0a94df;" dur="15s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animate attributeName="offset" values=".100;.80;.60;.40;.20;0;.20;.40;.60;.80;.100" dur="15s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1" transform="matrix(0.9999999999999999, 0, 0, 0.9999999999999999, 0, 0)">
        <g>
            <path class="cls-3 wave wave--3" d="M13.58,164.11l-8.65,28.6s29.6-9.31,73.82-9.31,82.14,19.29,138.67,19.29,81.97-17.29,146.65-17.62,91.45,15.96,150.31,15.96,107.08-17.62,152.3-17.62,87.46,9.31,120.38,10.97,41.9-.67,57.2-2.66l8.31-27.6s-17.29,6.98-51.21,7.32-88.46-15.01-120.05-14.96c-53.54-.33-111.73,19.29-159.95,19.29s-104.09-17.29-149.31-17.62-84.8,16.63-146.32,16.29-100.42-17.94-134.35-17.96c-49.22-.04-77.81,7.65-77.81,7.65Z" />
            <path class="cls-3 wave wave--2" d="M28.13,121.21l-6.32,20.29s11.64-8.65,56.2-8.65,83.14,16.29,142,15.96,87.46-13.96,152.3-13.8,97.43,15.8,151.64,13.8,97.1-14.79,144.99-13.71,94.44,10.39,132.68,11.05,54.87-3.81,54.87-3.81l5.65-21.13s-16.63,4.66-53.87,3.99-93.78-13.97-136.34-12.97-84.47,13.97-148.65,13.97-81.14-14.74-150.97-14.02-87.79,18.39-150.64,18.39-91.45-15.35-129.03-15.68c-49.55-.33-64.51,6.32-64.51,6.32Z" />
            <path class="cls-3 wave wave--1" d="M873.45,83.63l-4.66,18.62s-21.61,3.61-57.53,3.32c-41.57-.33-79.81-11.97-128.36-14.06-44.85-1.94-74.09,13.45-126.7,14.12-99.1,1.27-120.05-9.84-179.24-12.36s-101.09,17.62-152.97,16.96-66.18-13.3-130.02-14.63c-41.57-.87-59.52,7.32-59.52,7.32l6.98-19.29s19.62-6.65,55.87-6.98,75.85,12.77,99.1,14.3c45.56,2.99,58.53-1,109.41-9.98,50.88-8.98,115.44-3.66,143.33,1.66,36.58,6.98,82.47,8.32,129.36,2.33,46.89-5.99,85.46-15.8,125.7-8.73,40.24,7.07,120.71,17.71,169.26,7.4Z" />
        </g>
    </g>
    <style type="text/css">
        path.wave {
            fill: url(#gradient);
        }

        path.wave {
            animation: fadeIn 2.5s ease-in forwards;
        }

        @keyframes fadeIn {
            from {
            opacity: 0;
            }
            to {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
    </style>
</svg>
```

Comment: *The snippet below shows exactly the problem I'm facing* — no it doesn't. You haven't explained what this SVG is *supposed* to be doing, and you haven't described any of the efforts you made to solve this issue by yourself. You also haven't bothered to create a [mcve], so you're asking people here to do a lot of work just to find out what the problem is. Good luck with that.

Comment: how can I reproduce this problem? Can you help me with that? I'm a fast learner, and if you  *really* want to help, and not *cry* about working for someone else, then you might help me. because this is a forum for helping people as long as I remember.

Comment: Your testcase looks pretty similar to me on both Chrome and Firefox so what differences am I supposed to see?

Comment: hello, have you tried from Chrome mobile?